# Running swift condition just once on translation

Tags: ios, swift

I created a `UIView` and a `UIImageView` which is inside the `UIView` as a subview, then I added a pan gesture to the `UIImageView` to slide within the `UIView`, the image slides now but the problem I have now is when the slider gets to the end of the view `if movex > xMax`, I want to print this just once `print("SWIPPERD movex")`. The current code I have there continues to print `print("SWIPPERD movex")` as long as the user does not remove his/her hand from the `UIImageView` which is used to slide

```
private func swipeFunc() {

    let swipeGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(acknowledgeSwiped(sender:)))
    sliderImage.addGestureRecognizer(swipeGesture)
    swipeGesture.delegate = self as? UIGestureRecognizerDelegate
}

@objc func acknowledgeSwiped(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    if let sliderView = sender.view {
        let translation = sender.translation(in: self.baseView) //self.sliderView
        switch sender.state {
        case .began:
            startingFrame = sliderImage.frame
            viewCenter = baseView.center
            fallthrough
        case .changed:
            if let startFrame = startingFrame  {

                var movex = translation.x
                if movex < -startFrame.origin.x {
                    movex = -startFrame.origin.x
                    print("SWIPPERD minmax")
                }

                let xMax = self.baseView.frame.width - startFrame.origin.x - startFrame.width - 15 //self.sliderView
                if movex > xMax {
                    movex = xMax
                    print("SWIPPERD movex")
                }

                var movey = translation.y
                if movey < -startFrame.origin.y { movey = -startFrame.origin.y }

                let yMax = self.baseView.frame.height - startFrame.origin.y - startFrame.height //self.sliderView
                if movey > yMax {
                    movey = yMax
                    //                        print("SWIPPERD min")
                }

                sliderView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: movex, y: movey)
            }
        default: // .ended and others:
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, animations: {
                sliderView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
            })
        }
    }
}


override func point(inside point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
    return sliderImage.frame.contains(point)
}
```

Comment: You could move your codes under your `.changed` state to `.ended`.

Comment: @Glenn this could work but if a user moves the ImageSlider to the left instead of the right, the `.ended` is called also. I want to be able to move it only in the right direction

Comment: Check my answer. I think it would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to use the `.ended` state instead of `.changed` state, based on your requirements. And you've mentioned you want to get the right direction only. You could try below to determine if the swipe came from right to left, or vice-versa, change as you wish:

```
let velocity = sender.velocity(in: sender.view)
let rightToLeftSwipe = velocity.x < 0
```